# XSLT - Select corresponding access tag based on latest unique key

Tags: xslt, key, unique, distinct-values

I am new to XSLT, I have following scenario where I need to select corresponding access tag based on latest unique key tag.

I am using XML to insert data in DB, for tag F47127 I have 4 access tag and 4 key tag which is related in sequence for example first access tag is related to first key tag and so on. Now in the following example, for key tag 1st and 2nd are identical and 3rd and 4th are same so in output XML, the last key of each group that is 2nd and the 4th key should get included with corresponding access tag i.e. 2nd and 4th.

Input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:ProductActivityData_852_MT xmlns:ns0="http://tbccorp.com/a2a/SAP/michelin">
<STATEMENT2>
        <F47127 action="UPDATE_INSERT">
            <TABLE>F47127</TABLE>
            <access>
                <MJEDTY hasQuot="Yes">D</MJEDTY>
                <MJEDSQ>1</MJEDSQ>
                <MJEKCO>00000</MJEKCO>
                <MJEDOC>170301001</MJEDOC>
                <MJEDCT hasQuot="Yes">PA</MJEDCT>
                <MJEDLN>010000</MJEDLN>
                <MJEDST>852</MJEDST>
                <MJEDER hasQuot="Yes">S</MJEDER>
                <MJEDDL>1</MJEDDL>
                <MJEDBT>117263</MJEDBT>
                <MJPNID>0000107719</MJPNID>
                <MJPACD hasQuot="Yes">QS</MJPACD>
                <MJCITM>00875</MJCITM>
                <MJXRT hasQuot="Yes">CV</MJXRT>
                <MJAN8>00107719</MJAN8>
                <MJMCU hasQuot="Yes">        3029</MJMCU>
                <MJLITM hasQuot="Yes">BFG-00875</MJLITM>
                <MJAITM>00875</MJAITM>
                <MJDSC1 hasQuot="Yes">BFG-00875</MJDSC1>
                <MJDSC2 hasQuot="Yes">SELLOUT</MJDSC2>
                <MJTRDJ>117060</MJTRDJ>
                <MJTRUM hasQuot="Yes">EA</MJTRUM>
                <MJTRQT>-1.000</MJTRQT>
                <MJKCO>00003</MJKCO>
                <MJDGL>117060</MJDGL>
                <MJGLPT hasQuot="Yes">IN30</MJGLPT>
            </access>
            <access>
                <MJEDTY hasQuot="Yes">D</MJEDTY>
                <MJEDSQ>1</MJEDSQ>
                <MJEKCO>00000</MJEKCO>
                <MJEDOC>170301001</MJEDOC>
                <MJEDCT hasQuot="Yes">PA</MJEDCT>
                <MJEDLN>010010</MJEDLN>
                <MJEDST>852</MJEDST>
                <MJEDER hasQuot="Yes">S</MJEDER>
                <MJEDDL>1</MJEDDL>
                <MJEDBT>117263</MJEDBT>
                <MJPNID>0000107719</MJPNID>
                <MJPACD hasQuot="Yes">QS</MJPACD>
                <MJCITM>00875</MJCITM>
                <MJXRT hasQuot="Yes">CV</MJXRT>
                <MJAN8>00107719</MJAN8>
                <MJMCU hasQuot="Yes">        3029</MJMCU>
                <MJLITM hasQuot="Yes">BFG-00875</MJLITM>
                <MJAITM>00875</MJAITM>
                <MJDSC1 hasQuot="Yes">BFG-00875</MJDSC1>
                <MJDSC2 hasQuot="Yes">SELLOUT</MJDSC2>
                <MJTRDJ>117060</MJTRDJ>
                <MJTRUM hasQuot="Yes">EA</MJTRUM>
                <MJTRQT>-1.000</MJTRQT>
                <MJKCO>00003</MJKCO>
                <MJDGL>117060</MJDGL>
                <MJGLPT hasQuot="Yes">IN30</MJGLPT>
            </access>
            <access>
                <MJEDTY hasQuot="Yes">D</MJEDTY>
                <MJEDSQ>1</MJEDSQ>
                <MJEKCO>00000</MJEKCO>
                <MJEDOC>170301001</MJEDOC>
                <MJEDCT hasQuot="Yes">PA</MJEDCT>
                <MJEDLN>010020</MJEDLN>
                <MJEDST>852</MJEDST>
                <MJEDER hasQuot="Yes">S</MJEDER>
                <MJEDDL>1</MJEDDL>
                <MJEDBT>117263</MJEDBT>
                <MJPNID>0000107719</MJPNID>
                <MJPACD hasQuot="Yes">QS</MJPACD>
                <MJCITM>14340</MJCITM>
                <MJXRT hasQuot="Yes">CV</MJXRT>
                <MJAN8>00107719</MJAN8>
                <MJMCU hasQuot="Yes">        3029</MJMCU>
                <MJLITM hasQuot="Yes">BFG-14340</MJLITM>
                <MJAITM>14340</MJAITM>
                <MJDSC1 hasQuot="Yes">BFG-14340</MJDSC1>
                <MJDSC2 hasQuot="Yes">SELLOUT</MJDSC2>
                <MJTRDJ>117060</MJTRDJ>
                <MJTRUM hasQuot="Yes">EA</MJTRUM>
                <MJTRQT>6.000</MJTRQT>
                <MJKCO>00003</MJKCO>
                <MJDGL>117060</MJDGL>
                <MJGLPT hasQuot="Yes">IN30</MJGLPT>
            </access>
            <access>
                <MJEDTY hasQuot="Yes">D</MJEDTY>
                <MJEDSQ>1</MJEDSQ>
                <MJEKCO>00000</MJEKCO>
                <MJEDOC>170301001</MJEDOC>
                <MJEDCT hasQuot="Yes">PA</MJEDCT>
                <MJEDLN>010030</MJEDLN>
                <MJEDST>852</MJEDST>
                <MJEDER hasQuot="Yes">S</MJEDER>
                <MJEDDL>1</MJEDDL>
                <MJEDBT>117263</MJEDBT>
                <MJPNID>0000107719</MJPNID>
                <MJPACD hasQuot="Yes">QS</MJPACD>
                <MJCITM>14340</MJCITM>
                <MJXRT hasQuot="Yes">CV</MJXRT>
                <MJAN8>00107719</MJAN8>
                <MJMCU hasQuot="Yes">        3029</MJMCU>
                <MJLITM hasQuot="Yes">BFG-14340</MJLITM>
                <MJAITM>14340</MJAITM>
                <MJDSC1 hasQuot="Yes">BFG-14340</MJDSC1>
                <MJDSC2 hasQuot="Yes">SELLOUT</MJDSC2>
                <MJTRDJ>117060</MJTRDJ>
                <MJTRUM hasQuot="Yes">EA</MJTRUM>
                <MJTRQT>-14.000</MJTRQT>
                <MJKCO>00003</MJKCO>
                <MJDGL>117060</MJDGL>
                <MJGLPT hasQuot="Yes">IN30</MJGLPT>
            </access>
            <key>
                <MJEDOC>170301001</MJEDOC>
                <MJEDCT hasQuot="Yes">PA</MJEDCT>
                <MJEKCO>00000</MJEKCO>
                <MJLITM hasQuot="Yes">BFG-00875</MJLITM>
            </key>
            <key>
                <MJEDOC>170301001</MJEDOC>
                <MJEDCT hasQuot="Yes">PA</MJEDCT>
                <MJEKCO>00000</MJEKCO>
                <MJLITM hasQuot="Yes">BFG-00875</MJLITM>
            </key>
            <key>
                <MJEDOC>170301001</MJEDOC>
                <MJEDCT hasQuot="Yes">PA</MJEDCT>
                <MJEKCO>00000</MJEKCO>
                <MJLITM hasQuot="Yes">BFG-14340</MJLITM>
            </key>
            <key>
                <MJEDOC>170301001</MJEDOC>
                <MJEDCT hasQuot="Yes">PA</MJEDCT>
                <MJEKCO>00000</MJEKCO>
                <MJLITM hasQuot="Yes">BFG-14340</MJLITM>
            </key>
        </F47127>
    </STATEMENT2>
```

Output XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:ProductActivityData_852_MT xmlns:ns0="http://tbccorp.com/a2a/SAP/michelin">
<STATEMENT2>
        <F47127 action="UPDATE_INSERT">
            <TABLE>F47127</TABLE>
            <access>
                <MJEDTY hasQuot="Yes">D</MJEDTY>
                <MJEDSQ>1</MJEDSQ>
                <MJEKCO>00000</MJEKCO>
                <MJEDOC>170301001</MJEDOC>
                <MJEDCT hasQuot="Yes">PA</MJEDCT>
                <MJEDLN>010010</MJEDLN>
                <MJEDST>852</MJEDST>
                <MJEDER hasQuot="Yes">S</MJEDER>
                <MJEDDL>1</MJEDDL>
                <MJEDBT>117263</MJEDBT>
                <MJPNID>0000107719</MJPNID>
                <MJPACD hasQuot="Yes">QS</MJPACD>
                <MJCITM>00875</MJCITM>
                <MJXRT hasQuot="Yes">CV</MJXRT>
                <MJAN8>00107719</MJAN8>
                <MJMCU hasQuot="Yes">        3029</MJMCU>
                <MJLITM hasQuot="Yes">BFG-00875</MJLITM>
                <MJAITM>00875</MJAITM>
                <MJDSC1 hasQuot="Yes">BFG-00875</MJDSC1>
                <MJDSC2 hasQuot="Yes">SELLOUT</MJDSC2>
                <MJTRDJ>117060</MJTRDJ>
                <MJTRUM hasQuot="Yes">EA</MJTRUM>
                <MJTRQT>-1.000</MJTRQT>
                <MJKCO>00003</MJKCO>
                <MJDGL>117060</MJDGL>
                <MJGLPT hasQuot="Yes">IN30</MJGLPT>
            </access>
            <access>
                <MJEDTY hasQuot="Yes">D</MJEDTY>
                <MJEDSQ>1</MJEDSQ>
                <MJEKCO>00000</MJEKCO>
                <MJEDOC>170301001</MJEDOC>
                <MJEDCT hasQuot="Yes">PA</MJEDCT>
                <MJEDLN>010030</MJEDLN>
                <MJEDST>852</MJEDST>
                <MJEDER hasQuot="Yes">S</MJEDER>
                <MJEDDL>1</MJEDDL>
                <MJEDBT>117263</MJEDBT>
                <MJPNID>0000107719</MJPNID>
                <MJPACD hasQuot="Yes">QS</MJPACD>
                <MJCITM>14340</MJCITM>
                <MJXRT hasQuot="Yes">CV</MJXRT>
                <MJAN8>00107719</MJAN8>
                <MJMCU hasQuot="Yes">        3029</MJMCU>
                <MJLITM hasQuot="Yes">BFG-14340</MJLITM>
                <MJAITM>14340</MJAITM>
                <MJDSC1 hasQuot="Yes">BFG-14340</MJDSC1>
                <MJDSC2 hasQuot="Yes">SELLOUT</MJDSC2>
                <MJTRDJ>117060</MJTRDJ>
                <MJTRUM hasQuot="Yes">EA</MJTRUM>
                <MJTRQT>-14.000</MJTRQT>
                <MJKCO>00003</MJKCO>
                <MJDGL>117060</MJDGL>
                <MJGLPT hasQuot="Yes">IN30</MJGLPT>
            </access>
            <key>
                <MJEDOC>170301001</MJEDOC>
                <MJEDCT hasQuot="Yes">PA</MJEDCT>
                <MJEKCO>00000</MJEKCO>
                <MJLITM hasQuot="Yes">BFG-00875</MJLITM>
            </key>
            <key>
                <MJEDOC>170301001</MJEDOC>
                <MJEDCT hasQuot="Yes">PA</MJEDCT>
                <MJEKCO>00000</MJEKCO>
                <MJLITM hasQuot="Yes">BFG-14340</MJLITM>
            </key>
        </F47127>
    </STATEMENT2>
</ns0:ProductActivityData_852_MT>
```

Kindly provide your guidance.

Regards,
NP

Comment: Is that comparison of the `key` elements based on a particular child element value? Or based on the complete contents? Are you using an XSLT 2.0 or 3.0 processor so that `deep-equal` or `serialize` comparison is possible to identify such duplicates?

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for your reply...

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for your reply... the comparison is based on the key and latest unique key to be selected and corresponding access tag for the key has to be considered. I am using XSLT 2.0.

Comment: How exactly do you decide that a `key` element is distinct, based on a particular child element like e.g. `MJEDOC`, based on all child elements, based on the complete contents including any attributes? And which XSLT 2.0 processor do you use?